# Javascript string conversion to 'Title Case' returns no output

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I can't pinpoint where the error in the code is, it produces no output:

```
function capitalize (x) {
        var arr = x.split(' ');
        var output = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            output.push(arr[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+arr[x].slice(1));
        };

        return output.join(' ');
    }

    alert(capitalize("the quick brown fox"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `arr[x]` should be `arr[i]`.

```js
function capitalize (x) {
        var arr = x.split(' ');
        var output = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            output.push(arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+arr[i].slice(1));
        };

        return output.join(' ');
    }

    alert(capitalize("the quick brown fox"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was so used to using [x] as the placeholder haha.

Answer (score 1):

Short one-line solution:

```
var str = "the quick brown fox",
    capitalized = str.split(" ").map(function(w){ return w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1); }).join(" ");

console.log(capitalized);   // "The Quick Brown Fox"
```

Comment: That's awesome, I  wouldn't of thought of the program being done like that.